# xml insertion at specific point of xml file

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to insert the following line into my xml file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/livesearch.xsl"?>
```

immediately after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

in my xml file.

Currently I use this (awful) method:

```
$G['xml'] = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/livesearch.xsl"?>', $G['xml']);
```

What is the correct way to do this with DomDocument in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line you want to insert is called a [processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-pi). You can add it with DOM like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root/>');

$dom->insertBefore(
    $dom->createProcessingInstruction(
        'xml-stylesheet',
        'type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/livesearch.xsl"'
    ),
    $dom->documentElement
);
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/livesearch.xsl"?>
<root/>
```

On a sidenote, it might feel wrong to use `str_replace` but if it works … it works.