# Tkinter drop down menu goes into endless loop

Tags: python, tkinter, arcpy

I am using the following snippet of code adopted [from here](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/drop-down-menu-in-tkinter-290056.html) I need it to wait for the user to choose an option and then fill that into the rest of the code (to add to an xml file -a metadata generator program I am working on [with details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091381/code-being-dropped-from-xml-created-using-python))

```
from Tkinter import *

def print_it(event):
   print var.get()

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set("Set Copyright for: " + str(File))
OptionMenu(root, var, "Internal Use Only","Internal & Community Use","Whole Of Government Use", "Project Specific Licence","No licence constraints on ATGIS/TRC use", command=print_it).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

## should this be part of the def above?

```
for node in tree.findall('.//copyright'):
    node.text = str(var) # not sure how to call the output.
```

Comment: @Hoxieboy - Your comment got deleted (??). I don't want to use the def print_it -I wasn't quite clear why it was there in the original program and the script didn't work when it was commented out. I just want the script to ask the user for the input, put it into the xml file and then continue autofilling or asking other questions as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started the event loop with:

```
root.mainloop()
```

Looks like you just need a place to exit the loop and do your other processing.
For example, since the print_it process seems ideally placed you could modify it like so:

```
def print_it(event):
    print var.get()
    root.quit()
```

Now, whenever print_it is executed the mainloop is exited- whatever code is
below "root.mainloop()" would be executed right away.  So you could carry on from there...

Comment: Thanks mate...that was so simple. I really have to spend time learning the basics properly rather than just learning what's needed to get a job done.